Removing data-contrast and data-cpp-props span code from TinyMCE
It seems when users are pasting from a Word document in sharepoint or somewhere other than desktop, Word is putting in a lot of random span code. These get pasted into the TinyMCE we are using as part of our CMS.
eg> <span data-ccp-props="{"201341983":0,"335559739":160,"335559740":259}"> </span>
<span class="TextRun SCXW130510947 BCX8" data-contrast="auto"><span class="NormalTextRun SCXW130510947 BCX8"> </span>
How do we filter these out when editors paste it in - any one got suggestions.
I tried setting this in the TinyMCE settings but it doesn't work. See image
tinmycsettings
